# Remote Rejected branch is currently checked out in GIt

Tags: git, egit

I have clone an "sample" branch project from remote repository. I have modified code and commit in local "sample" branch.now i am trying to push remote "sample" branch by that time i am getting Remote Rejected.

How can i push changes to local sample to remote sample branch?
Ref mapping is "refs/heads/sample:refs/heads/sample" for EGit

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Did you try to Push the branch or Did you try to push the commit?

Comment: Can you list the steps or share a screenshot  ?